# Git Not In Sync with Local Branch

Tags: git, github, pentaho

I am not sure what is wrong. I have a basic understanding of git, but I am not an expert.

In my remote branch, I have a file that has a bunch of changes, etc in it.
In my local branch, this file is completely empty.

When I open up github, and the file, I notice it has something like this, so I believe something is out of sync:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:my_repo/category_1/run_daily_jobs/summary_daily_job.kjb
      <xloc>1328</xloc>
      <yloc>80</yloc>
=======
      <xloc>1280</xloc>
      <yloc>128</yloc>
>>>>>>> 44abcxyzbunchofvalues:my_repo/summary_daily_job.kjb
```

Based on the comments, here is what I have done:

1. Went to github
2. Found the file
3. Googled "how to read a merge conflict in github" and edited the file appropriately.
4. Ran "git pull origin/my_branch"

When I ran this command here is what the message said:

```
From my_repository
* branch   my_branch   -> FETCH_HEAD
updating some value
Fast-forward
.../name_of_file.kjb | 367 --------------------
1 file changed, 367 deletions(-)
```

5. For some reason, the file is still blank though when I open it in the software I am using (Pentaho). Maybe this is a software issue at this point though?

Here is how I edited my file, compared to what I have above:

```
  <xloc>1328</xloc>
  <yloc>80</yloc>
```

Comment: This is a merge conflict. The simplest fix is to edit the file to keep the lines exactly as you want them (removing the extra lines added by git). Then git add the file and the git commit (to complete the merge, which git was unable to do for you earlier because of the conflict).

Comment: Is there a way to see a list of all merge conflicts? I tried typing "git diff --check" but that didn't come back with anything.

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles `git status`?

Comment: I think just git status will tell you if you still have conflicts.

Comment: Git status says everything it up to date :/

Comment: Well, there you go - all is well? If git doesn't know you have any conflicts, either something has gone horribly wrong or (more likely) you don't. I suppose you could just run a file search for `HEAD:` in your files if you think the former is possible.

Comment: I am unsure because when I open the file up locally, it's completely blank, but when I go to git hub to view that branch, it has all the contents and git status says "nothing to commit, working tree clean". Let me try the original comment suggestion.

Comment: btw, if I end up getting fired for screwing up git, does anyone need a business intelligence developer? lol, jk, wish me luck.

Comment: After I edited the changes in Github directly, I typed git pull origin/my_branch , but it seems my local branch has not updated with the remote branch?

Comment: Did you check if your configured remote branch is the right one (git remote -v)? And what does git pull return?

Comment: When I typed that command, the fetch and the push match exactly

Comment: I edited my original post to reflect what happened in the git pull message

Comment: Can you just open the file in a text editor and see if it's still empty? Maybe the merge conflict markers could be making the file appear as corrupted and therefore just showing as blank by your software.

Comment: I did, it's not empty there though. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere..

Comment: Confirmed, I made a mistake when editing the original file, my problem is now solved. Someone post an "answer" and I will mark it as solved.

Comment: Thank you so much you guys. I do not have a huge understanding of git and everyone I know I taught myself by reading a book.

I never had to deal with merge conflicts before and now I know how to handle them in the future. Everything now works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the guys in the comments posts an answer within 72 hours, I will mark their answer as the solution and not mine since their comments helped me solve this.

What is going on is called a Merge Conflict.

It occurs when I make changes to one branch, switch to another branch and make changes, and then try to merge branches.

The way you solve this is by going into Github, editing the sections that contain "<<<<<<<<<<<<" and ">>>>>>>>>" and removing either the line above or below the "=======" line. You also want to obviously remove the "<<<<<<" and ">>>>>>>>" lines.

If you go to open up your file in  and it looks blank or get an error message, you made a mistake when editing the file to get rid of the Merge conflicts.